# Is there any way to block users from accessing WebRTC connection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I was wondering if there's any way that I can block curtain users from connecting to a specific device (using device's ip address) without first having to create a data channel and then see if the user is on a blacklist.

I tried and succeeded in making a blacklist by attaching an id to every single user, sending it to the host and then checking if the user is blocked, in which scenario the WebRTC signal would be terminated but I hope there's a different solution because I am opening myself to some possible exploits.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to make a blacklist based on ip addresses or you have a third-party way to authorise users. Also, do you have a global black list or is it per-user (is blocked user should be prevented from making any connections at all or only to specific users)?

Comment: For the first thing, I could have both, either ip address or user id with firebase backend. The black list is per user

Comment: WebRTC is a direct peer-to-peer communication protocol/technology. So as long as the connection is established you have no control over it. But you can do what you need in yous signaling back-end depending on the technology you use.

Comment: ICE candidates contain IP addresses, you can abort connection if you find certain IP in them, this should happen before connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

In order to establish a peer-to-peer WebRTC connection, you first need to make an offer/answer exchange over some signalling channel.  That is the right time to make authorisation decisions: if the peer is not authorised to access the media stream, it should never have received an offer or answer in the first place.

The reason why this is secure is that the WebRTC media is encrypted, and that the offer and answer contain data that is necessary in order to decrypt the stream.  No offer or answer, no cryptographic keys, and therefore no way to access the stream.

*(More accurately, the offer and answer contain data that is used to authenticate a peer-to-peer key exchange, but the simplified description given above should be good enough for now.)*